# Finding records that have a corresponding record some time in the future

Tags: mysql, sql, singlestore

I have table of records (currently it is a columnstore) that has the following layout:

```
id  | person_id | practice_key | order_date
-------------------------------------------
1   | 001       | prac-A       | 1501098844
2   | 001       | prac-A       | 1516996444
...
```

`id`, `person_id` are UUID's (stored as `CHAR`), `practice_key` is `VARCHAR` and `order_date` is epoch seconds stored as `NUMERIC`,

I want to only select `person_id`'s that have `order_date`'s at least six months in the future.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT MIN(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date))) min_order_date, person_id 
FROM the_table WHERE 
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date)) >= 
DATE_ADD(MIN(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date))), INTERVAL 6 MONTH);
```

and

```
SELECT MIN(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date))) min_order_date, person_id 
FROM the_table WHERE 
DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date)) >= 
DATE_ADD(MIN(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(order_date))), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY person_id;
```

But I get the following error: `[HY000][1111] Invalid use of group function`

I'm using MemSQL v6.0

Comment: In case you're still struggling with this, see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

After clarifying his position, I'd try the following. It simply joins on the table, and grabs the users first/last order. (**You should join straight from the `persons` table instead of orders, to avoid duplication**, and the additional `GROUP_BY` statement at the bottom. (Attatched [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8b4e/21) showing this works):

```
SELECT
  orders.person_id,
  first_order.order_date AS min_order_date,
  last_order.order_date AS max_order_date
FROM `orders`
LEFT JOIN `orders` first_order ON (
    first_order.person_id = orders.person_id 
    AND first_order.order_date = (
        SELECT MIN(order_date)
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE person_id = orders.person_id
    )
)
LEFT JOIN `orders` last_order ON (
    last_order.person_id = orders.person_id 
    AND last_order.order_date = (
        SELECT MAX(order_date)
        FROM `orders`
        WHERE person_id = orders.person_id
    )
)
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(last_order.order_date) >= DATE_ADD(FROM_UNIXTIME(first_order.order_date), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY person_id
```

Comment: still getting the same error `Invalid use of group function`

Comment: @daniel0mullins See my update. You do not need `MIN()` in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @daniel0mullins Because you're grouping by the person ID, you'll only get 1 result per user, containing the min order date that is >= 6 months from now.

Comment: I'm still not sure that's what I'm looking for. I want to return rows where a person has orders at least six months greater than their earliest order date

Comment: Oh! One sec @daniel0mullins, I'll update my answer

Comment: @daniel0mullins Updated

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE(MIN(FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.order_date))), t1.person_id 
FROM the_table t1
INNER JOIN the_table t2 ON t1.person_id=t2.person_id
AND DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.order_date)) >= DATE_ADD(DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.order_date)), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
GROUP BY t1.person_id;
```

Comment: I don't want order dates that are greater than six months from now. I want to select rows where the same person has an order date 6 months after the order date in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: I edited answer, check if it helps you. cheers

Comment: Hm, unconvinced!!!!!

Comment: It should be `DATE(MIN(FROM_UNIXTIME(t1.order_date)))` in your SELECT statement

Comment: Yeah, sorry, but general idea was there :)

Comment: While my answer *does* work, this one is a bit simpler, because it only involves one table join. You can see this answers sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c8b4e/27). Have an upvote sir.

Comment: *Actually* strangely enough, the SELECT statement is returning the wrong result. `DATE(MIN(FROM_UNIXTIME(t2.order_date)))` does indeed return the right result, but is this always going to be the lowest order date?

Comment: yeah,  i made copy/paste mistake :(, it should be t2. Table t2 should have only order_date values that have coresponding dates from t1 that are 6 months in future